# Cannot connect to a service from the browser

Tags: node.js, http, curl

I just installed Rocket.Chat and I can access it when doing a curl request from its installation server:

The command `curl http://my-ip:3000/` show me the index.html file just fine.

But accessing the same address from the browser `http://my-ip:3000/` does not respond.

I disabled my ufw firewall and it didn't help.

Comment: can you show us your code in node? It seems that you aren't returning any content to the client side

Comment: By `does not respond`, what is the HTTP request/response situation in browser dev tool? Is the request sent? Or is it always `pending` for response that never comes back? Or the response comes back with status 200 but the content is empty? Please provide a bit more information.

Comment: @Roljhon I don't know what code you refer to. I just downloaded and configured Rocket.Chat on my Linux box. I haven't produced any code at all. I only set some environment variables.

Comment: When requesting the `http://my-ip:3000/` address, I get the message `This site can’t be reached
my-ip took too long to respond.
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

Comment: @shaochuancs I opened the Chrome dev console (F12) but it show nothing. There is no response coming back.

Comment: Is the request sent? You can check this information in `Network` tab

Comment: @shaochuancs No, it doesn't seem so. I opened the Chrome Network tab with the All filter, and then pressed the Enter key on the IP address, it started humming, but nothing was ever displayed in the Network tab. Only the dev console at the very bottom showed a connection time out.

Comment: @Stephane weird issue, have you tried other browsers?

Comment: @shaochuancs Firefox behaves the same, it keeps humming but never connects. I think it is a network issue. Again, it only worked in curl and from the server itself. The same curl request from my dev machine hangs. `$ curl my-ip:3000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to my-ip port 3000: Connection timed out`.

Comment: hmmm, I guess this is a network environment issue, which has nothing to do with your web server or browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not provide code it's difficult to help you ... I think that maybe it's provoked by the app response. The app response is not setted to the content-type "text/html".
I say that because, when you create a NodeJS App with httpServer, if you don't set the content-type, when you go on the browser to your app, the app will not answer; but if you go on the terminal and use curl, the app will answer.
Regards.

Comment: I wish I had more code to show. I reckon it is a network issue instead.